# How many consumers does Spark start for Kinesis stream?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I have a Spark Cluster (1.6.1) with 1 master and 4 slaves running on Mesos. The spark job that i am running process data from Kinesis Stream. The code works fine except i can see that Spark is using two slaves heavily.

Upon more investigation, i see that Kinesis stream lease is only given to one machine and each datum is replicated with one more machine.

See the Spark UI image below for details

[image]

My question is why Spark is not utilizing other two slaves ?
Does Spark always start only one listener at max ? Is it dependent on number of shards in Kinesis stream ?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the number of Amazon Kinesis receivers created are a multiple of executors so that they are load balanced evenly across all the executors.

Reference - https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx3ET30EGDKUUI2/Implementing-Efficient-and-Reliable-Producers-with-the-Amazon-Kinesis-Producer-L